# Cross-Origin Request Blocked issue when integrating Lightning Component with external app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-out

I am trying to integrate Lightning Components with an external app using Lightning Out, code is mentioned below. I am getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked error, I have already added https://localhost:8443 in CORS section on SFDC to add localhost whitelisted origin.

Please let me know what could be causing the issue.

```
$Lightning.use("c:POCApp", function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:POC",
        {},
        "myDivId",
        function(cmp) {
            console.log('component created');
            console.log(cmp);
        });
    },"https://{MyDomain}.my.salesforce.com","AccessCode");
```

Comment: Is this issue resolved ? I am facing same issue with lightning out. I have added my domain in CORS (hosted app on heroku) but getting same cors error.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a proper HTTPS external url with a domain .Salesforce Lightning Out will not work with local host .

You may want to try using a simple node set up on the Heroku instead .Here is a sample app on [Node with Heroku](https://github.com/msrivastav13/NodeLightningOut) for reference .

Comment: Thanks Mohith, I will check and update the results on the post.

Comment: I added the domain name instead of localhost to CORS, but it still did not work. I am also not able to make Rest API calls. I am trying to connect to a developer account.

Comment: What is the error now?Also the access code should be Bearer sessionId

Comment: It is still giving us the same error. Domain not matches Access-Control-Allow-Origin. we have registered the domain in CORS section and other REST APIs are working fine, except for the Lightning Component. We are using Username Password OAuth Authentication and I am using Access Code generated to make this integration. Does that matter?